# How to properly route unauthenticated user to the Login Page in MVC .NET6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, .net-6.0

The only users that should see the list of contacts are authenticated users.

Inside the `Contacts Controllers`, I've been testing different file paths to route the unauthenticated users to the login screen to no avail.

When routing to anything inside the Area folder, exactly how would you go about writing the file path?

I've tried:

`Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/Login.cshtml`

`~/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/Login.cshtml`

`~/Account/Login`

```
namespace ContactPro.Controllers
{
    public class ContactsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ContactsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
          if (User.Identity != null &&  User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
          {
            return View(await _context.Contacts.ToListAsync());
          }

          else
          {
            return View("~/Account/Login");
          }

        }
         
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you can't redirect to a view that doesn't belong to the redirecting controller and isn't shared. Method `View` accepts a **file name without path**. It looks for the specified view in folder `/YourProjectName/Views/RedirectingControllerName` and in folder `/YourProjectName/Views/Shared`.

I advise you to use *redirecting to action, not to a view*. Create an action that will just return the view you need (in the controller that owns the needed view) and redirect to it when you need:

```cs
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it would be to use the `[Authorize]` attribute on your controller or actionmethod that requires logged in users. You can then define to what actionresult they should be redirected if they are not authenticated, in your program startup, when configuring your authentication.

Comment: `Authorize` attribute often doesn't work. In my team, it worked for 2 people and didn't work for 5 people (when we were starting to develop our FExchanger) — that was in September, and we still don't know what the matter was. It's easier to use `RedirectToAction`.